# Make request just after the initialization using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two http services. First one is online and it can get request SEND_DATA and than it sends data to second one using post request SAVE_DATA. I want to make second service when it starts to be able to make request SEND_DATA to first one and than get it by request SAVE_DATA. The problem is, if I send request from second one in autowired, first gets this request and sends it to second, but the second isn't fully initialized by that time and it can't get this request. What is the best solution to this?

first

```
@GetMapping(value = SEND_DATA)
public ResponseEntity<String> sendData() {
    ...
    postRequest(SAVE_DATA)
    ...
}
```

second

```
@Autowired
public Second() {
    ...
    getRequest(SEND_DATA)
    ...
}

@PostMapping(value = SAVE_DATA, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> saveData(@RequestBody String value) {
     save(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a distributed system, you cannot rely on internal communication between 2 beans(services). I suggest you having code to check availability before calling.

```
@Service
public class FirstService {

   private AtomicBoolean isSecondServiceOk;

   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1_000L)
   void checkingSecondServiceAvailability(){
       ... check response from SecondService if it respond, 
                           isSecondServiceOk.set(true)
   }

   ... check isSecondServiceOk available before calling SecondService

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@PostConstruct`:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private OtherService otherService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        otherService.doSomething();
    }
```

The method, which must be void but can have any visibility, is called after this bean is initialized, and that means of course that the injected bean is initialized too.